# problem with UI of image buttons in android app

Tags: android, user-interface, android-relativelayout

in my app i am placing 4 image buttons at the botton of the page. But according to my layout the image looks different in each device. I want the image to be the same in all devices.

Following is the layout of my image buttons

```
 <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tabLayout" android:layout_width="match_parent" 
           android:background="@drawable/tab_bar" android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_weight="0.1">
    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_width="match_parent">
        <ImageButton android:layout_marginLeft="35dip" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/homeBtn" android:background="@drawable/home"   android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center"></ImageButton>
        <ImageButton android:layout_marginLeft="35dip" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/homeBtn" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/addBtn"  android:background="@drawable/add"    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center"></ImageButton>
        <ImageButton android:layout_marginLeft="35dip" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/addBtn" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/srchBtn" android:background="@drawable/search" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center"></ImageButton>
        <ImageButton android:layout_marginLeft="35dip" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/srchBtn" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/helpBtn" android:background="@drawable/help"   android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center"></ImageButton>          
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Following are the images of my layout. I want my layout to be as in image1 and image2 is currently the image i am getting.

[image]

How to get as like the image 1 in all android devices. Please help me friends

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the others have mentioned its best you use a linear layout , but what you also need to do is provide a padding to linear layout, i am guessing 5dp should look good.

Here is how it might look :

[image]

And here is the code for the same

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp" android:background="#a0a0a0"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button android:text="Button" android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
    <Button android:text="Button" android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
    <Button android:text="Button" android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
    <Button android:text="Button" android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd reccomend you to use LinearLayout. It's much easier to align your buttons horizontally using it. Just set their `android:layout_width` property to `fill_parent` and `android:layout_weight` to `1`. Hope this helps.